# Why is this regression in Stata not progressing nor returning an error code?

Tags: stata, logistic-regression

I am running a multi-level logistic regression in Stata on multiple imputed data with the following command:

`xi: mi estimate, cmdok post: melogit outcome i.var1 i.var2 i.var3, difficult || id:`

I have succeeded in running similar models with the same covariates and different outcomes. These models only take 1 to 2 minutes using my dataset (approx. n=130,000 with n=10 imputations).

For other outcomes, even after many hours, Stata reaches a certain point and is running "something" but I'm not sure what (i.e. the circle in the bottom right is spinning). I used `set trace on` to check what was happening under the hood (last approx. 100 lines of output below). I'm not familiar with Mata. Stata reaches this point and seemingly doesn't progress any further, but doesn't return an error code and stop the program. Can anyone suggest why Stata is struggling to proceed any further with the regression, or suggest alternatives to avoid this problem? The same issue occurs both with `melogit` and `meglm` with a `link(logit)` and `family(binomial)`.

```
    - syntax name(name=maxmin) [, NEGH TOLerance(numlist ma
> x=1 >=0) LTOLerance(numlist max=1 >=0) NONRTOLerance NRTOLerance(numlist max=1 >=0)
>  QTOLerance(numlist max=1 >=0) GTOLerance(numlist max=1 >=0) ITERate(numlist max=1 
> >=0) NOTCONCAVE(numlist max=1 >=0) ndami DIFficult HALFSTEPonly DOOPT SEArch(name) 
> Repeat(passthru) Bounds(string) SCore(string) noWARNing noCLEAR noLOg DOTs SHOWTOLe
> rance SHOWNRtolerance SHOWSTEP TRace COEFDIffs GRADient HESSian noSKIPline noOUTput
>  Level(cilevel) moptobj(string) * ]
                              - if `:length local nrtolerance' {
                              = if 0 {
                                opts_exclusive "nrtolerance() `nonrtolerance'"
                                }
                              - if `:length local qtolerance' {
                              = if 0 {
                                opts_exclusive "qtolerance() `nonrtolerance'"
                                }
                              - opts_exclusive "`nonrtolerance' `shownrtolerance'"
                              = opts_exclusive " "
                                ---------------------------- begin opts_exclusive ---
                                - version 8.2
                                - args opts optname errcode
                                - local opts `opts'
                                = local opts  
                                - local n 0
                                - while `"`opts'"' != "" {
                                = while `""' != "" {
                                  local ++n
                                  gettoken item`n' opts : opts, bind
                                  }
                                - if `n' < 2 {
                                = if 0 < 2 {
                                - exit
                                ------------------------------ end opts_exclusive ---
                              - if `:length local shownrtolerance' {
                              = if 0 {
                                local showtolerance showtolerance
                                }
                              - if "$ML_preserve" != "no" {
                              = if "no" != "no" {
                                if `:length local score' {
                                di as err "May not specify score() option unless" _n 
> "     a)  estimation subsample is the entire data in memory, or" _n "     b)  you s
> pecify nopreserve option on -ml model- statement (meaning" _n "         your evalua
> tion program explicitly restricts itself to obs." _n "         for which $" "ML_sam
> p==1."
                                exit 198
                                }
                                preserve
                                local N = c(N)
                                quietly keep if $ML_sample
                                if (`N' != c(N)) {
                                mata: Mopt_init_regetviews()
                                }
                                }
                              - if `:length local score' {
                              = if 0 {
                                SetupScore `"$ML_evaltype"' `"`score'"' $ML_n $ML_dim
                                local scores "`s(scores)'"
                                }
                              - local tropts `log' `dots' `showtolerance' `showstep' 
> `trace' `coefdiffs'
                              = local tropts      
                              - if "`tropts'" != "nolog" {
                              = if "" != "nolog" {
                              - local tropts `tropts' `gradient' `hessian'
                              = local tropts   
                              - if "`skipline'" == "" {
                              = if "" == "" {
                              - if "`iterate'" != "0" | `:length local tropts' {
                              = if "" != "0" | 0 {
                              - di
                              - }
                              - }
                              - }
                              - else {
                                local gradient
                                local hessian
                                local nolog nolog
                                }
                              - if "`search'" != "off" & "`iterate'" != "0" {
                              = if "off" != "off" & "" != "0" {
                                if "`search'" == "quietly" {
                                local sopts nolog
                                }
                                else {
                                if `:length local tropts' {
                                if "`tropts'" != "nolog" {
                                local sopts trace
                                }
                                else local sopts nolog
                                }
                                }
                                if "`search'" == "norescale" {
                                local sopts `sopts' norescale
                                }
                                Search `bounds', nopreserve `sopts' `repeat' `maxmin'
                                }
                              - tempname value b V iV
                              - `vv' mata: Mopt_maxmin()
                              = version 13: mata: Mopt_maxmin()
```

Comment: If I don't specify the random effect for `id` and use a model like `xi: mi estimate, cmdok post: melogit outcome i.var1 i.var2 i.var3, difficult` instead of `xi: mi estimate, cmdok post: melogit outcome i.var1 i.var2 i.var3, difficult || id:` the model converges with no issues. Why would specifying a random effect seemingly cause such problems?

Comment: You would be better off asking on Statalist: the question is not purely a programming issue. As a minor detail: `xi:` as a prefix command is, I suspect, redundant here. I doubt that is any kind of issue otherwise,

Comment: Now crossposted to Statalist.